# Git plugin not working

Tags: git, plugins

I have git-tf in my path but Git doesn't appear to see it. My understanding is that git should find plugins/extensions with names like `git-xxxx` in your path and let you execute them using `git xxxx`.

This is on a Mac running El Capitan (10.11.12).

```
$ type git-tf
git-tf is hashed (/Users/chris/Development/git-tf/git-tf)
$ which git-tf
$ git-tf --version
git-tf version 2.0.3.20131219
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
$ git --version
git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)
$ git tf
git: 'tf' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    tag
$
```

Someone requested I print out my $PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"
~/bin
~/Development/git-tf
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
$
```

A co-worker is on Yosemite and is not seeing the problem. I asked him to run the same commands and his output is below. Note the output from `which git-tf`:

```
$ type git-tf
git-tf is hashed (/usr/local/git-tfs/git-tf)
$ which git-tf
/usr/local/git-tfs/git-tf
$ git-tf --version
git-tf version 2.0.3.20131219
$ which git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
$ git --version
git version 1.8.4.2
$ git tf
usage: git-tf [--version] [--help] [--quiet|-q|--verbose] [<command...>]

The git-tf commands are:
  help       Displays usage information
  clone      Initializes a git repository from a TFS path
  configure  Configures an existing git repository to add to TFS
  checkin    Checks in changes to a TFS folder
  fetch      Fetch the latest code from TFS into FETCH_HEAD
  pull       Pulls the latest code from TFS and merge/rebase the changes into master
  shelve     Shelves the changes to a TFS folder
  shelvesets Lists the shelvesets available on the server. Provides a way to delete shelvesets
  unshelve   Unshelves a shelveset from TFS into the repository
$
```

Comment: This output is confusing. Why does `which` not print a path, but on the very next line you run `git-tf` and get output?

Comment: @DanLowe perhaps the current directory has the executable for git-tf, i.e the current dir must be `/Users/hidden-from-StackOverflow/git-tf/git-tf`? That's the only way the above output would make sense

Comment: @DanLowe, I find that odd as well and I think that might be related. I wasn't in the git-tf directory when I ran those commands. I'm wondering if this has something to do with El Capitan, specifically. A co-worker with Yosemite sees git-tf when doing `which` and his `git tf` is working.

Comment: Chris, can you please post the output of `echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"` ?

Comment: @AshutoshJindal, done. I also went ahead and removed the "hidden-from-StackOverflow" bit. I was being a little overly-cautious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git is not able to resolve commands in the path if the relevant path component uses shell shorthand like `~`. You will need to change

```
~/Development/git-tf
```

to one of these instead:

```
/Users/chris/Development/git-tf

$HOME/Development/git-tf
```

(tested on El Capitan using bash.)

Answer (score 2):

**Please see Dan Lowe's answer above about using the complete path for the directory containing the custom git command instead of abbreivating it with '~'**

---

(Leaving the following intact since it has a few niceties like greadlink)

I was able to reproduce the problem on OSX 10.8 with zsh (and find a work-around).

#### Create a custom command

```
# Make a directory to store the git-tf custom git command/extension
$ mkdir -p ~/Development/git-tf
$ cat ~/Development/git-tf/git-tf                                                                                  #! /usr/bin/env bash
    echo "Hello, Imma git command!"
```

#### Pre-requisites, make it executable and add it to PATH

```
$ chmod +x ~/Development/git-tf/git-tf
$ export PATH="$PATH:~/Development/git-tf"
# Confirm that it is indeed in the PATH
$ echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | grep tf

$ git tf
git: 'tf' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Did you mean this?
    tag
```

Nope, doesn't work

#### Work-around (copy custom command to git installation folder)

```
# Find out the location of the git installation
$ brew install coreutils  # to get GNU readlink which support '-f'
$ dirname $(dirname $(greadlink -f $(which git)))
$ cd $(!!)/libexec/git-core

$ cp ~/Development/git-tf/git-tf .
$ git tf
  Hello, Imma git command!
```